# Aviary SDK, delegate issue

Tags: objective-c, image-processing, delegates, uiimageview, aviary

Ok, so I'm following the Aviary Documentation Tutorial on how to setup an app, however I'm getting two errors.

[image: Errors]

The code is as follows

```
- (void)displayEditorForImage:(UIImage *)image
{
static dispatch_once_t onceToken;

dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
    [AFPhotoEditorController setAPIKey:kAFAviaryAPIKey secret:kAFAviarySecret];
});

AFPhotoEditorController *editorController = [[AFPhotoEditorController alloc] initWithImage:image2];

[editorController setDelegate:self]; //error is here

[self presentViewController:editorController animated:YES completion:nil];}
```

The error is the line `[editorController setDelegate:self];`, which returns the above error, I don't know how to fix this.
The example provided in the [documentation](https://developers.aviary.com/docs/ios/setup-guide#photo-editor-usage) has the same code and even the [sample app](https://developers.aviary.com/docs/ios/setup-guide#sample-app) has the same code but seems to work fine.
Is there something I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to indicate that your delegate class conforms to the `AFPhotoEditorControllerDelegate` protocol.

In your .m, usually just before the `@implemenation` line, add a class extension (you may already have one). Add the protocol there.

```
@interface ThirdViewController () <AFPhotoEditorControllerDelegate>

@end

@implementation ThirdViewController

// all your existing stuff

@end
```